# how to export const/let from an if statement?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have this problem that auth.currentUser.uid originally = null, and uid is loaded only after a few seconds, but the site has time to fall into error and I found that if you equate the constant to auth.currentUser.uid then it will be updated and it will work, but the problem is that the userUID changes only within the if statement, and I need to change it globally

```
  if (auth.currentUser != null) {
    let userUID = (auth.currentUser.uid);
  };



  console.log(userUID);



  useEffect(() => {

    const q = query(collection(db, "customers", auth.currentUser.uid, "subscriptions"));

    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (subscription) => {
          setSubscription({
            role: subscription.data().role,
            current_period_start:
              subscription.data().current_period_start.seconds,
            current_period_end: subscription.data().current_period_end.seconds,
          });
        });
      });
    }, [auth.currentUser.uid]);
```

Comment: Can you not put userUID as state? What do you need this variable for? Please show more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way if your user id is updated then it runs the query. And it will work as per the user change the value.

```
useEffect(() => {

if(auth.currentUser.uid){
    const q = query(collection(db, "customers", auth.currentUser.uid, "subscriptions"));

    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (subscription) => {
          setSubscription({
            role: subscription.data().role,
            current_period_start:
              subscription.data().current_period_start.seconds,
            current_period_end: subscription.data().current_period_end.seconds,
          });
        });
      });
}
}, [auth.currentUser.uid]);
```

Comment: the same issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')